# Start and Stop a Weblogic Server Remotely with WLST

Tags: oracle, weblogic, wlst

Platform: Windows Server 2016
I have a server running weblogic 12.2.1.3. Runs great. I have another server that only has oracle DB 19c installed and on that server there are some scripts that refresh the DB from a backup weekly. I'd like to modify db scripts on the DB server to use WLST and remotely reach over to the weblogic server and stop a managed server and start it again later in the script.

What do I need to install on the DB server to run WLST?

Comment: A simple solution is to exchange SSH keys, then ssh remotely from the DB server to the WL server and run commands. Another solution I implemented back in 2012, is to connect remotely to the admin console using JMX; however, the JMX interface is poorly documented. It was a lot of guesswork, but finally all worked like a charm.

Comment: Sorry, JMX is not one of my requirements. Neither is SSH keys. My requirements call for WLST. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 solutions :

1. Install WLS on your DB machine
2. Copy WLS java libs required by WLST. For instance with 12.1.3 :
   $ORACLE_HOME/wlserver/modules/features/weblogic.server.merged.jar
   $ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/modules/com.oracle.cie.config-wls_8.1.0.0.jar
   $ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/modules/com.oracle.cie.config_8.1.0.0.jar
   $ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/modules/com.oracle.cie.comdev_7.1.0.0.jar
   $ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/modules/com.oracle.cie.service-table_1.1.0.0.jar
   $ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/modules/com.oracle.cie.dependency_1.1.0.0.jar
   $ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/modules/com.oracle.cie.config-wls-schema_12.1.3.0.jar
   $ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/modules/com.oracle.cie.config-security_8.1.0.0.jar
   $ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/modules/com.oracle.cie.config-owsm_8.1.0.0.jar
   $ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/modules/com.oracle.cie.wizard_7.1.0.0.jar
   $ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/modules/com.oracle.cie.encryption_2.1.0.0.jar
   $ORACLE_HOME/wlserver/modules/com.oracle.css.weblogic.security.wls_7.1.0.0.jar
   $ORACLE_HOME/wlserver/modules/com.oracle.css.common.security.api_7.1.0.0.jar $ORACLE_HOME/wlserver/modules/com.oracle.css.weblogic.security_7.1.0.0.jar
3. Use WLS REST Management API to start/stop your managed servers from your DB machine. From my point of view it is the best solution. Read this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WLRUR/examples.htm#WLRUR193) for details.

Comment: Thank you so much.